# When I run this code, I get this error, why?

Tags: python

When I run my Python code, I get this **error**:

File "source_file.py", line 13
else:
^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
Process finished with exit code 1.

Here is my **code**:

```
if answer03 == "attack":
    print("That was not the greatest idea, you lost!")
       else:
        print("Good choice, you made it away safely!")
```

Comment: the else code should not be inside the if block

Answer (score 0):

Python is whitespace sensitive. The proper syntax is like this:

```
if answer03 == "attack":
    print("That was not the greatest idea, you lost!")
else:
    print("Good choice, you made it away safely!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Indentation of `else` is wrong (second `print` also):

```
if answer03 == "attack":
    print("That was not the greatest idea, you lost!")
else:
    print("Good choice, you made it away safely!")
```